# How can I cancel MouseWheel Windows Message in TRichEdit control to fix scrolling?

Tags: c++builder

In the application I'm working on, there is a `TListView` and a `TRichEdit` in a form.
When the user click an item in the `TListView`, it loads `TRichEdit` text. My problem occurs when the text is longer then the height of the `TRichEdit`.

If I scroll with the Mouse Wheel really quickly and I continue scrolling even when the scrolling bar is at bottom, then I click another item in the `TListview` (which make `TRichEdit->Text` change), the scrolling sometimes continues on the newly loaded text.

My hypothesis is that there is some kind of Windows Message not yet processed and when I click another item, the scroll message is read and the scrolling continue?!

I already tried to disable then enable the `TRichEdit` on the `TRichEdit` MouseLeave without success (scrolling continue when I change selected item of TListView).

I was wondering if anybody have any ideas?

**[edit]**

Ok so I'm trying the solution from Remy but `PeekMessage()` doesn't catch any `WM_VSCROLL`, `WM_HSCROLL`, `WM_MOUSEWHEEL`. I tried to catch it before and after the function `DescriptionChanged();` but neither of them catch the scroll message.

```
void __fastcall TfrmJob::lvDescriptionSelectItem(TObject *Sender, TListItem *Item, bool Selected)
{

    //Function where ListView load item into RichEdit->Text  
    DescriptionChanged();

    MSG msg;

    //Loop while there is messages ("If no messages are available, the return value is zero")
    while (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL /*reDocDetail->Handle*/ /*lvDescription->Handle*/, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE | PM_QS_INPUT) > 0)
    {
        //Trying to catch Scroll message
        if(msg.message == WM_VSCROLL || msg.message == WM_HSCROLL || msg.message == WM_MOUSEWHEEL)
        {
            TranslateMessage (&msg);
            DispatchMessage (&msg);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When changing the `RichEdit` text, try using a `PeekMessage()` loop to discard any pending `WM_VSCROLL`, `WM_HSCROLL`, and `WM_MOUSEWHEEL` messages that are still in the message queue.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Is it that I'm not using the right event that the PeekMessage doesn't have the scroll value? I would have though that putting the PeekMessage after the loading of the TRichEdit would have worked. I also tried in RichEdit OnChange event with no luck. I tried with GetMessage(). Do you have other suggestions maybe?

Comment: You missed the point of my suggestion.  You are suppose to *discard* the messages (ie, just ignore them), NOT *dispatch* them. But, if you are not getting the messages at all, then there is really nothing you can do. Maybe there is just an internal loop inside of the RichEdit itself at the OS layer to support smooth scrolling and such, and it is just taking time to catch up after the last scroll message was already processed.  Have you tried simply resetting the scroll position using `SetScrollInfo()` or `RichEdit.SelStart=0; RichEdit.Perform(EM_SCROLLCARET,0,0)`?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes I see what you were suggesting now! (Doing nothing instead of calling Dispatch) thank you. Should I remove my question since I didn't find a solution and it's not likely it's something that can be fix?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Oh! I didn't saw your last part of comment, I can try to reset it manually!

Comment: @RemyLebeau So I tried the `SelStart` but couldn't make it work. But I did found something interesting in the code: a function that override windows messages for the `RichEdit`! `void __fastcall TfrmJob::RichEditDocWndProc(TMessage &Msg)`. I'm able to catch the `WM_MOUSEWHEEL` in it (hourray!). I will continue investigating next Monday.